Problems with using ReactToPrint to print a React component
I've been trying to use the ReactToPrint library to make a print button that makes it possible to print everything inside a div. In console I receive the errors:

"react-to-print" did not receive a contentRef op…or a
optional-content param pass to its callback."
"There is nothing to print".

When console logging componentRef.current I receive undefined in console, so it's clear that it doesn't access the ref, but I can't figure out why? Any suggestions?
This is my component:
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';
import { HeaderText } from '../HeaderText/HeaderText';

export const StartPage = () => {

  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,
  });
  console.log(componentRef.current)

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={componentRef}>
        <HeaderText />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print</button>
    </>
  )
};


Make the ref with null:
const componentRef = useRef(null);

Use the ref attribute:
<div ref={componentRef}>

Full Version:
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';
import { HeaderText } from '../HeaderText/HeaderText';

export const StartPage = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef(null);
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current,enter code here
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={componentRef}>
        <HeaderText />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print</button>
    </>
  );
};

If there are still issues it might be a package problem
